# Difference between MSK and CPSK

Tags: phase, modulation, demodulation, linear-phase, gmsk

I'm trying to understand the differences between the MSK and CPSK transmission, but I am not understanding some things about it.

I understood that they are two signals without discontinuity, but what are the substantial differences between the two modulations?
I have not found documents that answer my doubts

Comment: Do you mean “CPSK” as in continuous phase shift keying? MSK is a specific variant of the greater family of CPSK signals.

Comment: @DanBoschen yes, my mistake. I can't understand what differences there are between the two types, CPSK and MSK, and what differences occur in the second

Comment: I just wrote up this recent post detailing what exactly "MSK" is and what its salient features are.  https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/82779/subquestion-from-iq-signal-to-fm-modulated-carrier-how-its-done/82787#82787 Both are constant envelope modulations that modulate the phase only and continuously (no abrupt phase transitions). MSK does this as the "minimum phase shift" needed to keep the symbols orthogonal. Please read the other post and update your question here if there is still something further to clarify.

Comment: Also MSK is not a CPSK as it has abrupt transitions in the phase trajectory at the symbol boundaries, but GMSK specifically combines the minimum spacing of MSK with the continuous phase of CPSK at the symbol transitions: GMSK is a subset of the general family of CPSK; this should answer your question together with the other link I provided: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/76167/difference-between-msk-and-gmsk/76169#76169 . If not, please let us know what is still not clear.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between MSK and GMSK?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/76167/difference-between-msk-and-gmsk)